# No show widget after Future executed

Tags: flutter, dart

Android Studio 4

Flutter project

here snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

 Future<bool> isGeolocationStatusDisabled() async {
  GeolocationStatus geolocationStatus = await getGeolocationStatus();
  return (geolocationStatus == GeolocationStatus.disabled);
}

 Widget _createMapInnerContainerLeft() {
    _logger.d("_createMapInnerContainerLeft: -> call_async_isGeolocationStatusDisabled()");
    return _createTurnOffGlobalLocationServiceContainerLeft();
  }




Widget _createTurnOffGlobalLocationServiceContainerLeft() {
    _logger.d("_createTurnOffGlobalLocationServiceContainerLeft:");
    return new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN, top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
        child:
            new Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          new Text("Geolocation service is turned off",
              style: _createNearestGazStationTextViewStyle(FontWeight.bold)),
          new Text("Turn on geolocation for the application",
              style: _createNearestGazStationTextViewStyle()),
          new Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: new Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _logger.d("click");
                      },
                      child: Text('Settings'.toUpperCase(),
                          style: _createNearestGazStationTextViewStyle()),
                      color: new Color(Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY),
                      textColor:
                          new Color(Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR))))
        ]));
  }
```

and here result:

[image]

But I need to show container after finish Future method `isGeolocationStatusDisabled()` . So I change code like this:

```
 Widget _createMapInnerContainerLeft() {
    _logger.d("_createMapInnerContainerLeft: -> call_async_isGeolocationStatusDisabled()");
    Future<bool> isGeolocationStatusDisabledFuture = isGeolocationStatusDisabled();
    isGeolocationStatusDisabledFuture.then((value) {
      return _createTurnOffGlobalLocationServiceContainerLeft();
    });
  }
```

And now widget not show:

[image]

Comment: Your should use @Neil's answer, but you should pay attention to compiler warnings/info. You should have seen something about that function not ending in a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a blank space is because your function is returning `null` as this is `Dart` default behaviour for functions that doesn't return values on all conditional paths.

The reason for the unhandled conditional path is because you're not awaiting your `Future` execution using the `await` keyword so the program starts executing the `isGeolocationStatusDisabled` function but doesn't wait for the result.

You should use a `FutureBuilder` to render a `Widget` on the result of a `Future` execution.

```
Widget _createMapInnerContainerLeft() {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: isGeolocationStatusDisabled(),
    builder: (context, futureData) {
      if (futureData.hasData) {
        _logger.d("_createMapInnerContainerLeft: -> call_async_isGeolocationStatusDisabled()");
        bool isGeolocationStatusDisabledFuture = futureData.data;
        if (isGeolocationStatusDisabledFuture) {
          return _createTurnOffGlobalLocationServiceContainerLeft();
        }
      }

      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  )
}
```

Go check out [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) page to learn more about `FutureBuilder`. You can also read up more on `Dart` `asynchronous` programming [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score 0):

This help:

```
Widget _createMapInnerContainerLeft() {
    _logger.d(
        "_createMapInnerContainerLeft: -> call_async_isGeolocationStatusDisabled()");
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: isGeolocationStatusDisabled(),
        builder: (context, projectSnap) {
          ConnectionState connectionState = projectSnap.connectionState;
          bool hasData = projectSnap.hasData;
          _logger.d("_createMapInnerContainerLeft: connectionState = $connectionState, hasData = $hasData");
          if (connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&  hasData != null) {
            _logger.d("_createMapInnerContainerLeft: -> call_showNearestGazStationViewMode");
            return _showNearestGazStationViewMode();;
          }
          _logger.d("_createMapInnerContainerLeft: -> call_Container()");
          return Container();
        });
  }


Future<bool> isGeolocationStatusDisabled() async {
  GeolocationStatus geolocationStatus = await getGeolocationStatus();
  return (geolocationStatus == GeolocationStatus.disabled);
}
```